# lotusnotes: creating a new field, update the already existing documents

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I create a new computed field called `txt_new` in a form, which has a default value based on some calculations between other fields.

I also create a new column in my view named `vwMain` which has the default value: `txt_new`.

The problem is that the column is empty considering the fact that the .nsf has already >10k documents. Is there any posibility to update/(re)save the documents in a safe method ?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write an agent which contains the default formula of your field `txt_new` and execute agent for all 10K documents. That should be fast enough or to be more exactly: there is no faster way.

Example for agent:

```
SELECT txt_new = "";
FIELD txt_new := ... here is your default formula code ...
```

Comment: This agent runs from a view window?

Comment: Yes, from a view. Depending on what you set as agent's target parameter (e.g. "All selected documents") you might have to select all documents.

Comment: I get something: Internal error processing command: incorrect number of parameters

Comment: You created a Formula agent? How does the formula look like?

Comment: Could you open a chat window, please? My default formula is quite "complex" and I would like to show it

Comment: Thanks! This 'method' is faster comparing to the above one, but that one works also!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an agent to run against all the documents in the view/selected documents only using

```
@Command([ToolsRefreshAllDocs])
```

Comment: `@Command([ToolsRefreshSelectedDocs])` refreshes the selected documents.

Comment: If I use this formula, it takes some quite long time... I have 10k => approx. 4  hours